# Selenium can't find elements by this XPath expression

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm trying to extract some odds from a page using [Selenium ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started), since the data is dynamic. The "find elements by XPath expression" usually works with these kind of websites for me, but this time, it can't seem to find the element in question, nor any element that belong to the section of the page that shows the relevant odds.

I'm probably making a simple error - if anyone has time to check the page out I'd be very grateful! Sample page: [Nordic Bet NHL Odds](https://www.nordicbet.com/en/odds#?cat=&reg=&sc=50&bgi=36)

```python
driver.get("https://www.nordicbet.com/en/odds#?cat=&reg=&sc=50&bgi=36")
time.sleep(5)
dayElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope']")
print(len(dayElems))
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: It's preferable not to use `time.sleep(5)` but wait for a specific element to appear or the spinning wheel disappear. The xpath itself is fine but will probably give the wrong element. Try right-clicking on the desired element in the browser and inspect it.

Comment: I've tried using WebdriverWait (until presence of element by Xpath) but it just goes to timeout. It seems selenium can't access this part of the website at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a problem I used to face...

---

It is in another frame whose id is SportsbookIFrame. You need to navigate into the frame:

```python
driver.switch_to_frame("SportsbookIFrame")
dayElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope']")
len(dayElems)
```

Output:

```
26
```

For searching iframes, they are usual elements:

```python
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
```

Comment: In this case there are two elements with the exact class name 'ng-scope'. Sometimes there will be three of them. They are parent divs that contain lots of divs under them and they look like this:

Comment: <div ng-repeat="marketgroup in marketGroups | filter:filterMarketGroups" class="ng-scope"></div>

Comment: function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

Comment: getElementByXpath("//div[@class='ng-scope']"), It can find them in the chrome console though

Comment: Does d mean driver in the code you've provided above? :)

Comment: Yes I should make it clear, gonna edit it now--- done,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165969/discussion-between-daniel-slatt-and-soulomoon).