# Selenium can't find elements even if they exist

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a simple selenium script to enter username and password to log in. Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\Aspire5\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://ven02207.service-now.com/")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_name"]')
username.send_keys('username')

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_password"]')
password.send_keys('this_is_password')
```

But I'm getting following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="user_name"]"}
```

I'm accessing [this](https://ven02207.service-now.com/) website from code. The XPath I've provided in code are exists on the page, but still it's returning `No Such Element Exception`.

What I'm missing here? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028909/selenium-cant-find-elements-by-xpath), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588759/selenium-cant-find-elements-even-after-timeouts) questions for this, but couldn't find exact answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to first switch to the frame.. since the `input` tag is inside the frame

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsft_main"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_id('user_name').send_keys('sarthak')
driver.find_element_by_id('user_password').send_keys('sarthak')
```

Comment: Perfect! But how would I know when to switch to a frame and when not? +1 and will accept

Comment: so you will have to take a look, is the iframe used and if yes then is the code you want to scrape inside it...

Comment: you just saved my life! thanks for the answer and for the explanation, it is all clear to me now. spent several hours looking for this help, and finally found it. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for element to present in DOM. So try to wait before getting web element 
    driverwebdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Aspire5\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

```
driver.get("https://ven02207.service-now.com/")

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="user_name"]"))
username.send_keys('username')

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="user_password"]'))
password.send_keys('this_is_password')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I've already tried this approach and it;s not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use escape slashes and you'll be fine

```
'//*[@id=\"user_name\"]'
'//*[@id=\"user_password\"]'
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck.