# Getting error: "is not a valid XPath expression." when trying to reference a field within service now

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium/Webdriver and Python to automatically fill a form and was successful with all fields but one. I have a feeling it's because it is inside of a div container and I don't know how to specify something inside the container. I am trying to change the value "Blank".

[This is what inspect element shows for the form field (highlighted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXYx7.png)

The error line is from here:

```
assignmentGroup = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*div[@class=“input-group ref-container”]//sys_display.sc_req_item.assignment_group')
```

I have also tried doing the full xpath (copied from chrome) like this:

```
assignmentGroup = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/span[1]/span/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
```

and like this, with and without the last *@id part:

```
assignmentGroup = web.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 form-field input_controls"]//div[@class="input-group ref-container"]//*[@id="sys_display.sc_req_item.assignment_group"]')
```

Which gets me this from CLI- Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:>xpath here<

Last, I tried getting whatever attribute was in this box, just to see if I can locate it.

```
assignmentGroupAttribute = web.find_element_by_css_selector("div.input-group.ref-container").get_attribute('sys_display.sc_req_item.assignment_group')
```

My 8 hours of experience in Python/HTML/CSS may not be enough for me to figure this out.. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. The `input` element you have highlighted has an `id` tag, try grabbing it by that

```
assignmentGroup = web.find_element_by_id("sys_display.sc_req_item.assignment_group")
```

Rule of thumb is to always search for `ID` or `Name` first, those are usually the most reliable.  If those aren't available you can go into `Xpath` or `CSS Selector`

Comment: Completely my fault for not including more html code, but it was still not working. I found out from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764405/selenium-cant-find-elements-even-if-they-exist that I need to switch to frame first. Then it worked. I will use ID or name first. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, yep. I had no way to see that :)  Good job in figuring it out, iframes can be tricky