# Selenium Can't Find Specific Div Despite Existing in Iframe

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web

I am trying to download the csv file from this link with selenium: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/annual-co-emissions-by-region and am encountering issues regarding finding the actual elements necessary to download the file. Here is my code so far:

```
driver.get("https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/annual-co-emissions-by-region")
    frame = driver.find_element_by_id("GTM-N2D4V8S")

    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

    downloadLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/figure/div/div[4]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/a")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", downloadLink)
```

Specifically, I am trying to find the second div underneath the element with this css selector `body > main > figure > div > div.DownloadTab`, which contains the download link. Unfortunatley, while I am able to find this parent element, I am unable to find the div I am looking for. From doing research, I think that this issue might have to do with the iframe, so I am trying to switch it with the code above (although it is not working). This link may be helpful: [Selenium can't find elements even if they exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764405/selenium-cant-find-elements-even-if-they-exist)

Thanks so much!

Comment: How do I accept an answer? No one has ever told me to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any ideas on the problem?

Comment: Try my answer, let me know if it worked for you and if there are any questions - don't hesitate to ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the page / elements fully loaded before accessing them and to use the correct locators.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/annual-co-emissions-by-region")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.download-tab-button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-track-note='chart-download-csv']"))).click()
```